# Get mouse coordinates relative to original image D3/Javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a large image I am loading into an SVG element:

```
<svg id="plate-svg" width="800px" height="500px">
    <image id="plate" xlink:href="plate_red.JPG" x="0" y="0" height="500px" width="800px"/>
</svg>
<div id="mpos"></div>
```

And I am setting the mouse position like this:

```
<script>
function mouseover(d, i) {
  var x = d3.mouse(this)
  d3.select('#mpos').text(x);
}
var plate = d3.select('#plate-svg')
plate.on("mousemove", mouseover);
</script>
```

However, I would like the coordinates of my mouse relative to the original large image. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean 'large image'? Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247209/d3-click-coordinates-are-relative-to-page-not-svg-how-to-translate-them-chrom?