# How to find the position of the rectangle in a SVG document when mouse clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I have a lot of square boxes inside a SVG document. How to find which box I have clicked showing which column and row position I clicked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [d3 click coordinates are relative to page not svg - how to translate them (Chrome error)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247209/d3-click-coordinates-are-relative-to-page-not-svg-how-to-translate-them-chrom)

Comment: How do you create your boxes?  How are they positioned in rows and columns when you draw it?  How about you update your question with some code?  [Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and you'll get a good answer.  Ask a poor question, you'll get poor answers or no answers at all.

Answer (score 0):

If your svg is in a html file and if you add a `clickable` class to each clickable element you could try to use javascript

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.clickable')
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  const element = elements[i];
  element.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(e.target);
  });
}
```

the event map a target property which is your clicked element.